# Error: Forms based authentication in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, forms-authentication, windows-server-2008-r2

I have followed this [tutorial](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806890.aspx) and setup everything to get ready to go with FBA.

When I choose Forms Authentication in Sign in page it just throws below error

[image: FBA Error]

and in Event Viewer this warning shows up:

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 3/31/2015 4:00:37 PM 
Event time (UTC): 3/31/2015 10:30:37 AM 
Event ID: 96dffdb339154bafa266d9706c90eb64 
Event sequence: 3 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/240113279/ROOT-2-130722714033267092 
Trust level: Full 
Application Virtual Path: / 
Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\1100\ 
Machine name: MYSERVER 

Process information: 
Process ID: 5376 
Process name: w3wp.exe 
Account name: DEMO\Administrator 

Exception information: 
Exception type: NullReferenceException 
Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at  
Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.Pages.FormsSignInPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)



Request information: 
Request URL: http://myserver:1100/_forms/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=/_layouts/15/Authenticate.aspx?Source=An unhandled exception has occurred.F&Source=/ 
Request path: /_forms/default.aspx 
User host address: ::1 
User: 0#.w|demo\administrator 
Is authenticated: True 
Authentication Type: Federation 
Thread account name: DEMO\Administrator 

Thread information: 
Thread ID: 17 
Thread account name: DEMO\Administrator 
Is impersonating: False 
Stack trace:    at

    Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.Pages.FormsSignInPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)



Custom event details:
```

Any solutions to resolve this problem?

When I gone through this [Test Lab Guide](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/2/9/129E9CB3-D9AD-4EE5-AE92-6E7ABE5F2A2A/tlg-sp2013-fba-claims.pdf) the requirement says to use **Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise With SP1** but i have installed  **Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard with SP1**, does that makes any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is the exact solution but it worked for me.

Here's what i did, I installed SQL Server 2012 Enterprise SP1 + SP2 instead of Express and Forms Based Authentication started working like a charm.

Thanks for your help guys.